# LessCss - extending css on the fly

Tags: css, less

I am aware of that you can declare a class :

```
.someclass { ... }
```

And then extend it

```
.otherclass { &:extend(.someclass all) }
```

But does the .someclass really has to be declared ?

In my case only callers will apply the logic and there is no need for someclass to have the logic declared as well, as it is only a placeholder for similar css.

It would be nice if there was a **&:extend(groupingFunction all)** .

**But maybe there is already?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Less don't support this "placeholder-equivalent".

Checkout this issue: [:extend mixins](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177).

You can use the "@import (reference)" feature to somewhat "simulate" this behavior but it can cause unexpected problems in some cases (there are quite a few issues about the import reference feature).